# Highchart : How to use images when using "General drawing"

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to create a diagram for my tasks by using Highcharts

And I assume that I could put some images, by using the `<img>` tag

```
ren.label('<img src="/images/test.jepg', 10, 82)
                        .attr({
                            fill: colors[0],
                            stroke: 'white',
                            'stroke-width': 2,
                            padding: 5,
                            r: 5
                        })
                        .css({
                            color: 'white'
                        })
                        .add()
                        .shadow(true);
```

but it doesn't work, how could I use images in General writing?

I want to make something like below.

[image]

jsFiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rttav/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an image like this:

```
      // SaaS client label 
      ren.image('http://lorempizza.com/80/60', 10, 82, 80, 60).add();
      ren.label('SaaS client<br/>(browser or<br/>script)', 10, 82)
        .attr({
          stroke: 'white',
          'stroke-width': 2,
          padding: 5,
          r: 5
        })
        .css({
          color: 'white'
        })
        .add()
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-image-on-chart/) from the [official docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.image) and updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rttav/11/